# Differential Amplifier Question

Tags: mosfet

[image]

[Taken from Razavi's Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits 2nd edition]

I'm not too sure what to do with this question. Here's what I think of the circuit

This doesn't look like a differential amplifier to me since there's only 1 input. From what, I see, M1 has a constant DC bias current through it of I1. I see the following relationship
$$I_2=I_{SS}-I_1$$
Leading to,
$$V_{out2}=V_{DD}-(I_{SS}-I_1)R_1$$

Note that I2 is the current through R1 and M2

As Vin small signal changes, this I1 is perturbed, which in turn perturbs I_2 which in turns adjusts voltage drop across R1 which leads to Vout2 having a small-signal change. **Now, I'm not sure how to get Vout1/Vin or Vout2/Vin.** I was thinking of maybe adjusting the equation up there and sub in the Id equation for I1 but that would leave me with a quadratic and squared Vin term.

Also if there's any experienced analog people out there. Is my thought process correct for understanding the circuit or along the right lines?

Comment: HINT: Diff inputs strive to make both inputs the same voltage, so under ideal conditions Vin = Vb and Vout1 = Vout2. If Vin != Vb then Vout1 and Vout2 equal the difference times the gain.

Comment: @Sparky256 That's the first time I've heard of that. So it's kind of like an op-amp with negative feedback which tries to close the gap between the two inputs and thus let's us make that V+ = V- statement.

Comment: Compute the gain of one-half the circuit, using standard GM and Rload. Then think about how much 100%, 50%, of the input signal goes to each half of the "diffpair". Think about how the common-source node behaves.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf how can I split the circuit up into two halves. I thought that's only possible when both sides are perfectly symmetrical?

Comment: Like my main issue is with the fact that, I can't split it down the middle like I always did with symmetrical circuits (i.e that Vss is no longer at AC ground for small signal analysis).